# How do I make a variation of a pre-existing class?

Tags: python

I am currently creating a game where each enemy has a specific AI. Each enemy is given an AI and statistic changes(health, damage, etc.). However, I also need to assign these enemies to an NPC slot before the game's main loop is run. The problem comes in because I need to identify the x-value and y-value of the enemy so the game knows where to place them. If I keep the x- and y-values as a parameter in the AI class, I have to repeatedly redefine them when I put them in an NPC slot(my slots are labelled 'NPC1', 'NPC2', and so on).

```
class PeonGrounded(object):
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, vel, aggrorange, health=20.0, kb=10, jumplength=10.0, jumpheight=2.0,
             jumpmomentum=0.25):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.vel = vel
    self.direction = 'R'
    self.standing = True
    self.health = health
    self.canMove = True
    self.jumplength = jumplength
    self.isJump = False
    self.canJump = True
    self.kb = kb
    self.jumpheight = jumpheight
    self.jumpmomentum = jumpmomentum
    self.neg = 1
    self.aggrorange = aggrorange
    self.aggroed = False
```

I now want to be able to define *some* parameters(everything but x, y, width, height) but leave others blank for defining later.

Comment: Just give default values for all of the parameters you don't want to have to specify up front.  You're already doing that for most of them, you just need to extend it to `vel` and `aggrorange`.

Comment: @jasonharper I can do that, but I need to change the parameter values depending on what enemy class it is, and I don't know how to define optional parameters in a variation class such as when I make a class like `class zombie(PeonGrounded)`. My problem was that I couldn't define my optional parameters when I created a new class from the main class, such as setting the zombie class's `self.vel = 3`. Sorry if my question was phrased in a way that misled you.

Comment: If the defaults differ, then give each subclass its own `__init__()` that has appropriate defaults, and just calls `super().__init__()` with all the parameters.